# a single application development targeted for both mobile and desktop platforms

Tags: ria

We are planning to develop an application that is targeted for mobile and desktop platforms.

Can I use the same code base to develop application that are targeted for mobile and desktop platforms.
If I can't, how much of it can I re use to develop desktop and mobile apps with easy way?.

Or, how i can achieve it by adding it within a single running application with some kind of logic with differet views?

We were having in mind EXTJs and Sencha Touch to combine but it seems less feasible for complex designs.

Expectations from the application are 
1. It should run smoothly on most of all windows browsers.
2. It should work with IPad, Android mobiles and Tabs.

Is there some other RIA framework that can help with desktop and mobile application to achieve my goal, then please suggest that alternate also?

Would appreciate if anyone can share their experiences for doing similar efforts.

or is it better to go with seperate application development.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be quite late for the original poster, I'm  posting this as another project to be considered for any one else looking for a cross platform GUI.

[Kivy](http://github.com/kivy/kivy) is another cross-platform GUI. Take a look at Some [Apps](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/kivy-users/_zleyIZHNMs) made using Kivy.

Kivy uses a GUI that is built on top of OpenGL E.S. 2.0, so you get Open GL acceleration as a bonus. It's built on top of python, so programming for it is easy.

Kivy also support iOS and Android apart from the regular desktop os's.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may look to follow pure MVC design in your application. Where your presenatation layer is independent of your business logic and is solely contributes to the GUI controlling, navigation, validation etc. 
In that case your business logic and data access layer would be same for all platforms and the development effort would be much lesser.

Comment: i was thinking to use sencha extjs and sencha touch where i can use different views but same model, store, controllers and same backend server and business logic for both plateform. But looking some better options before this implementation.